# How Google crawls Angular-based apps with HTML5 urls

Tags: django, angularjs, seo

I'm building a web application with the following url structure:

```
/                 is the landing page, not angular based
/choose           uses Angular, it basically contains search
/fund/<code>      also with Angular, contains specific data for a certain fund
```

There's no problem indexing `/`, it's just a plain and simple html, already SEO optimized. But I need both `/choose` and `/fund/...` being crawled by Google, that's the problem.

My app uses the HTML5 mode, and we never point to the app urls using hashbangs like `foo.com#!/choose`, always `foo.com/choose`.

Also, according to [Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?hl=pt-BR) on that matter, I put `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` on the head of every Angular page we have. But using *"fetch as google"* to inspect my site, I can't realise how Google's asking the pages for my server. I'm using Django on the backend and I built a middleware to catch `_escaped_fragment_` and act on it, but Google's never sending it.

So, simply put, my questions are:

- Why isn't Google fetching my urls using `_escaped_fragment_`?
- How Google will fetch the pages?

  1. `foo.com?_escaped_fragment_=/choose`
  2. `foo.com/choose?_escaped_fragment_=`

Comment: Google crawling of SPAs does only work with Hashtags.

Comment: I love that they can't even crawl their own framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the google [specs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification?csw=1), You should use

`foo.com/choose?_escaped_fragment_=hashfragment`.

But As mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-developers/Y_sdVXTrRSI), you don't seem to need `hashfragment` and the equal sign part since your url is already mapped on your Django server side. So, get rid of it and give it a try.

Your final url should look like this: `foo.com/choose?_escaped_fragment_`.

Hope it helps!